# Avoid line break when using jquery append() or html()

Tags: jquery, html, append, line-breaks

At first I have this in my DOM :

```
<li>
  <span>A</span>
</li>
```

When i do this :

`$("li").append("<span>B</span>");`

Here is what I got if I look into the DOM :

```
<li>
  <span>A</span>
  <span>B</span>
</li>
```

But I would like to have

```
<li>
   <span>A</span><span>B</span>
</li>
```

I need to display span on the same line in order to avoid displaying a white space between the two elements.

With javascript innerHTML the problem is the same as jQuery use it for append and html function.

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cm0s/Z9TTd/24/)

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you looked at the source code using firebug you would have seen it formatted as in your firs example.

Comment: And you're sure that a space appears when you do this?

Comment: It seems to work properly with `.append` as you have it: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/LZy6L/

Comment: There is no line-break, it's just the way your source-viewer formats it for readability.

Comment: the output for both cases is same

Comment: I made an error when posting the question. I'm trying to append a span to a li which already contains another span. I added a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can solve, or at least *avoid*, the problem by simply using `after()` in place of `append()`:

```
$("li span").last().after("<span>C</span>");
```

```js
$("li span").last().after("<span>C</span>");
$('#generatedHTML').text($('li').html());
```

```css
#generatedHTML {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-family: mono;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
}
#generatedHTML::before {
  content: "Created HTML: ";
  color: #999;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>A</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="generatedHTML"></div>
```

Also, please note that I corrected your HTML: an `li` is *only* valid when a direct-child of a `ul` or `ol` (it should not be contained within *any* other element).

Also, you could use a somewhat more-complicated alternative:

```
$("li").append("<span>B</span>").contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove();
```

```js
$("li").append("<span>B</span>").contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove();
$('#generatedHTML').text($('li').html());
```

```css
#generatedHTML {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-family: mono;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
}
#generatedHTML::before {
  content: "Created HTML: ";
  color: #999;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>A</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="generatedHTML"></div>
```

While it's been some time, I thought it was worth also adding a plain JavaScript version of the above:

```
let htmlToAppend = '<span>B</span>',
  span = document.querySelector('li span');

span.insertAdjacentHTML(
  'afterend', htmlToAppend
);
document.querySelector('#generatedHTML').textContent = span.parentNode.innerHTML;
```

```js
let htmlToAppend = '<span>B</span>',
  span = document.querySelector('li span');

span.insertAdjacentHTML(
  'afterend', htmlToAppend
);
document.querySelector('#generatedHTML').textContent = span.parentNode.innerHTML;
```

```css
#generatedHTML {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-family: mono;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
}

#generatedHTML::before {
  content: "Created HTML: ";
  color: #999;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>A</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="generatedHTML"></div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).
  - [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).
  - [`let` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).
  - [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType).
  - [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
- jQuery:

  - [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/).
  - [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
  - [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/).
  - [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, and I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Comment: I like references :) And even if it looks a bit stranger than before it makes total sense and works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

So, the answer is that there is no case what you're seeing in source code: the only line or several lines markup, they both implemented by browser as equal DOM. The white space problem can be caused by wrong styles. So, i recommend you to check them firstly.

Comment: I already checked the white space problem and found different solutions. The better one is to put spans on the same line. It seems there is no CSS solution which is cross-browser (without using hacks for certain browsers)

Comment: This is not true. White-space between inline elements (and a line-break is counted as one) will lead to a white-space in the rendered HTML. [There are some hacks around it](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) but most of them need control of the HTML source so the questioner has a valid point.